Suddenly installing 24.04 on a KVM virtual machine started crashing it has work before
I have been installing Ubuntu server 24.04 on my VM hosts using KVM and virt-manager without a problem. suddenly this process started crashing on all my VM hosts. I am even using the same ISO I did in earlier installs. I suspect it's an issue with install time downloads.

There's not enough information to debug this. "Started crashing"? At what stage? What crashes? Are there logs?
